# Using Twitter sync with Cognito

Tags: java, android, twitter, synchronization, amazon-cognito

I think it will be hard question. Anyone had dealt with cognito and Twitter. Last do not support OpenID. So have any idea, how can synchronize these two things.

Cognito documentation said only: Using Cognito, developers can store information such as user ... that are not natively supported by Cognito, such as Twitter or LinkedIn™

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here

Comment: Cognito hasnt native support for Twitter. But anyway, must be some solutions!

Comment: As of April 30, 2015 Amazon Cognito natively supports Twitter and Twitter's Digits login. More information is in [the Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/twitter/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use twitter, you would need to implement it as a developer authenticated identity provider http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities

The basic flow would be:

1. Implement an identity provider that prompts the user to log in with twitter on the device.  Using the token twitter returns, call the authentication backend you create to validate the token using the twitter api.
2. After validation, call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity from your authentication backend using developer credentials.  Return the identity id and OpenID Connect token back to the device.
3. The Cognito credentials provider will then exchange the OpenID Connect token for aws credentials tied to that twitter identity.

Full details about the identity provider interface and flow are available in the dev guide: 
[iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#using-developer-authenticated-identities) or [Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#using-developer-authenticated-identities)

Comment: I created identity provider with own pool. And connect google+ and facebook. But dont quite understand connecting Twitter. Can u show in code, please? I get Twitter token, what next?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manage the communication with twitter yourself, you may want to consider integration with an another service such as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), which itself integrates with Cognito via OpenId Connect tokens and no back end.

See this [blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/01/08/integrating-auth0-with-amazon-cognito-in-ios/) and this [sample app](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX/tree/master/Examples/Cognito.Swift) for an iOS example.

**Update 2015-04-30:** Amazon Cognito has been updated to natively support Twitter and Digits. Read more on the [AWS Mobile blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx398OODXZXXAMZ/Announcing-Twitter-and-Digits-Support-for-Amazon-Cognito) as well as the [Amazon Cognito developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/twitter/).

Comment: This way dont suite Twitter. Last dont support OpenID.

Comment: @GenkaKasyan you can use Twitter login to federate with Auth0, which then vends the OpenId Connect token which can be used directly with Cognito.